# How to group conditional filters in Magento 2 data provider

Tags: magento2, database

In my component/ui/dataprovider I have the following.

```
class TheProvider extends DataProvider
{
    /**
     * Get collection data
     * @return array
     */
    public function getData()
    {
        $this->setFilter();
        return parent::getData();
    }

    /**
     * Adds filter to collection for view
     * @return void
     */
    protected function setFilter()
    {
        $this->addFilter(
        $this->filterBuilder
            ->setField('status')
            ->setValue('pending')
            ->setConditionType('eq')
            ->create()
        );
    }
}
```

So obviously 'setFilter()' applies the following conditions to the data source...

```
WHERE status='pending'
```

What I want to do is apply the following logic in the filter.

```
WHERE (status = 'pending' AND store_id = 1) OR (status='processing' AND store_id = 2)
```

It seems I can easily create chained AND conditions, but I can't find anything in the code that allows me to chain OR conditions.

Is this possible without having to modify the model's collection query?